# D3 line and points fail to update on new data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have a websocket feeding datapackets to a d3 graph. The function graphData() is definitely being called, according to the console log. The data is updated when the page is refreshed, but it doesn't update live, as it should. The axes do seem to update, though. I have read, and believe that I have followed, the .enter().append() process, but I must have made a mistake:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var margin = {top:20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left:50},
        width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var svg = d3.select("#visualisation").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

        function graphData(data) {
            console.log("graphdata called")

            var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
            var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

            var valueline = d3.line()
                .x(function(d) { return x(d.time); })
                .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

            x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.time; }));
            y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.value; }));

            var valueLine = d3.line()
                .x(function(d) { return x(d.time); })
                .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });

            var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(data);
                circles.exit().remove();
            circles.enter().append("circle")
               .attr("r", 2)
               .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.time); })
               .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
               .merge(circles);

            var line_graph = svg.selectAll("path")
                .data([data])
            line_graph.exit().remove();
            line_graph.enter().append("path")
                .attr("class", "line")
                .attr("d", valueLine)
                .merge(line_graph);

            var xaxis = svg.selectAll(".x")
                .data([data])
            xaxis.enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .merge(xaxis).call(d3.axisBottom(x));

            var yaxis = svg.selectAll(".y")
                .data([data])
            yaxis.enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .merge(yaxis).call(d3.axisLeft(y));


        };
</script>
```

Comment: This might not fix it, but you don't really need to do `.data()` and `.enter()` on axis calls. You can just call the new scale into them `svg.select(".y").call(d3.axisLeft(y))`

Comment: @pmkro Understood, but then where does the append go? Sorry, I'm very new to D3!

Comment: I would make 2 functions. One that initially creates the chart, then one that updates it with new data. In the creation use `xaxis = svg.append("g").attr("class", "y axis").call(d3.axisBottom(x))` and in the update you just need `svg.select(".x").call(d3.axisBottom(x))` after your xscale domain has been updated.

Comment: @pmkro That makes sense, I'll rewrite it and then edit the code in the question

Comment: if you could create a fiddle or the like that would be best.

Comment: @pmkro Actually, does that make sense? I would need to call a different function for the first datapacket, as d3.axis*() cannot create an axis without data, presumably. I'll try putting it into a fiddle, but there's no easy way of getting the datapackets through

Comment: Just show how your packet call is calling the chart function. You can always create an empty chart with no data and update from there.

Comment: @pmkro https://jsfiddle.net/f7vvs3gb/1/ graphData is called when the websocket receives a message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167196/discussion-between-pmkro-and-alex).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle with final solution](https://jsfiddle.net/8gzv7rrh/1/). I moved most of your generators out of your `graphData` function and into the top code.

```
  var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data);

  circles.exit().remove();

  circles.enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 2)
    .merge(circles)
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return x(d.time);
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return y(d.value);
        });

  var line_graph = svg.selectAll(".line")
    .data([data])

  line_graph.exit().remove();

  line_graph.enter().append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .merge(line_graph)
        .attr("d", valueLine);

  svg.select(".x").call(d3.axisBottom(x));
  svg.select(".y").call(d3.axisLeft(y));
```

I also made some modifications to how you were updating your axis. `.enter().append()` is not required for axis to update correctly, just need to recall the scale.